# Export values from a dataframe from coordinates lat/Long of another dataframe

Tags: r, coordinates

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2` (see below)

```
    df1<-structure(list(Lat = c(-89.75, -89.25, -88.75, -88.25, -87.75, 
-87.25, -86.75, -86.25, -85.75, -85.25), Long = c(-179.75, -179.25, 
-178.75, -178.25, -177.75, -177.25, -176.75, -176.25, -175.75, 
-175.25), NOy = c(3.91364542905387e-15, 3.91952637880666e-15, 
3.92540732855945e-15, 3.93128785479576e-15, 3.93716880454855e-15, 
3.93803955441832e-15, 3.93390010440509e-15, 3.92976065439186e-15, 
3.92562120437863e-15, 3.9214817543654e-15), NHx = c(1.14955574068474e-15, 
1.1571213330905e-15, 1.16468681961713e-15, 1.17225241202289e-15, 
1.17981800442865e-15, 1.18044237358989e-15, 1.17412562538574e-15, 
1.1678088771816e-15, 1.16149212897745e-15, 1.1551753807733e-15
)), .Names = c("Lat", "Long", "NOy", "NHx"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
df2<- structure(list(x = c(148.1516, 4.5206, 5.9981, -51.4500008, -125.3336, 
-125.2909, -124.9004, -82.1556, -98.4808, -98.4839), y = c(-35.6566, 
51.3092, 50.3051, -1.72000003, 49.8673, 49.8705, 49.5346, 48.2167, 
55.8796, 55.8792)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The two dataframe contains lat and long coordinates. I would like to export the values NOy and NHx from df1 which somehow are within the coordinates of the df2. The output would be a dataframe containing the coordinates values of df2 with their respective NOy and NHx values exported from df1. The `df3` shows how the output could look like. The NA values should obviously the real data exported from df1 instead of NA.

```
df3<- structure(list(x = c(148.1516, 4.5206, 5.9981, -51.4500008, -125.3336, 
-125.2909, -124.9004, -82.1556, -98.4808, -98.4839), y = c(-35.6566, 
51.3092, 50.3051, -1.72000003, 49.8673, 49.8705, 49.5346, 48.2167, 
55.8796, 55.8792), NOy = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), NHx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "NOy", "NHx"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Show the result you expect from the example. This line is unclear `based on the coordinates of the df2.` That can mean many things. Please clarify.

Comment: I changed it to " I would like to export the values NOy and NHx from df1 which somehow are within the coordinates of the df2". Hope this is more clear.

Comment: You sidestepped what Pierre actually asked. What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: "Well: You'll never find a programming language that frees you from the burden of clarifying your ideas.
Cueball: But I know what I mean!" - Randall Munroe, xkcd

Comment: I'm not sure you understand @SimonB. You currently have two dataframes as example. Please add a `df3` that reflects the output that should result.

Comment: @PierreLafortune. Alright. I added a potential output in the question.

Comment: Leaving NA values does not help. The values are the most important part. They will show any potential helper the logic you are using. Your vague explanation isn't sufficient. Are you aware that a lat, lon combination is a point. There is nothing "within". You probably mean coordinates that match exactly to the table. In that case you may be looking for `merge(df1, df2, by=1:2, all.y=T)`

Answer (score 0):

The `df1` originally comes from a ncdf file, therefore I instead created a raster object for each of the variable NOy and NHx as such:

```
library(raster)
NOy_Raster <- raster("file.nc", varname="NOy_deposition")
NHx_Raster <- raster("file.nc", varname="NHx_deposition")
```

I then extracted the values of NOy and NHx with the points coordinates in the dataframe `df2` as such:

```
df3 <- data.frame(coordinates(df2),
                  df2$x, 
                  extract(NOy_Raster, df2), 
                  extract(NHx_Raster, df2))
```